# "Top of Page" button's hover effect sticks when clicked, how do I undo this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, responsive

I have a top of page button that gets bigger and turns gray when hovered, however when clicked it looks maintains it gray color and larger size, which covers up parts of my website, especially on mobile phones.  I would just like for it to return to its normal color and size, and at best, it doesn't even need to have the hover effect on mobile so if there is a way to disable hover in a media query that would be great also. How can I accomplish this?

https://jsfiddle.net/68z5gtfm/2/

```
  <div  class="top_link_position">
                <a  class="back-to-top" href="#page_top" title="Top">
                <button class="top_btn"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up fa-2x"></i></span></button>
                </a>

.top_link_position {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0%;
    right: .20%;
    z-index: 600;
}

.top_btn {
    border: 1.5px solid white;
    background: rgb(39, 38, 38);
    padding: .7rem .7rem;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.top_btn:hover,
.top_btn:focus {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(167,167,167,.97), rgba(167,167,167,.97));
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
}

.top_btn:hover,
.top_btn:focus,
.top_btn:active {
    outline: 0;
}

.top_btn:active {
    border: 1.5px solid white;
    background: rgb(39, 38, 38);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.top_btn:visited {
    background: rgb(39, 38, 38);
    color: white;
} 

.back-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0em;
    right: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: .35em;
    display: none;
}
.back-to-top:hover .fa-2x {
    font-size: 3em;
    transition-duration: .5s;
}
```

Comment: `.back-to-top` is missing in the fiddle you specified

Comment: should be edited now